# Domain of two different functions and combined functions equation

Tags: functions

I want to ask a question about the domain of two different functions in relation to an equation.

I was provided with two different functions:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}, x > 3$$
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1-x}{x}, 0 < x < \frac{1}{4}$$
$$g(x) = 2x^2 - 3, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now, I was asked to solve the equation:

$$fg(x) = \frac{1}{8}$$

This is what I did.

$$g(x) = f^{-1}(\frac{1}{8})$$
$$2x^2 - 3 = 7$$
$$2x^2 = 10$$
$$x^2 = 5$$
$$x = ±\sqrt{5}$$

This is what is given in the marking scheme, but I thought as $f(x)$ had domain $x>3$ I thought only $\sqrt{5}$ would be accepted.

Why are both values accepted?

Comment: @David I've corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are dealing with the composite function $f\circ g$, the initial restriction (i.e. the domain of your equation) is: $$x\in D_g=\mathbb{R}, \\ g(x)\in D_f\Leftrightarrow g(x)\geq3\Leftrightarrow 2x^2-3\geq3\Leftrightarrow x^2\geq3$$ 
i.e.: $$x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{3})\cup(\sqrt{3},+\infty)$$
This is why both solutions are accepted.